# Netlogo turtles need to move same time at two different target location

Tags: scheduling, netlogo, job-scheduling, agent-based-modeling

- Sorry, I am yet beginner with Netlogo programming i am trying to
  schedule the jobs on machine based on their priority.
- At the moment only  product1 turtle is process by one machine turtle.
  While other products turtles are not been run on the machines which
  are idle e.g machine2 and machine3. Currently they are waiting for
  the other loop to finish to process the next.
- What i want to achieve is Product1 needs only Machine1 for operation.
  while  P2 needs M2 and M3, P3 needs M1,M2 and M3. So when Product1
  turtles are on M1, other turtles should move to their corresponding
  targets and schedule themselves

  ```
    breed [product1 productA]
      breed [product3 productB]
      breed [product2 productC]
      breed [machine1 machineA]
      breed [machine2 machineB]
      breed [machine3 machineC]
      breed [schedulers scheduler]

      globals [Priority]



      product1-own

      [

       productID
      productLength
      arriveTime
      startTime
       finishTime


       ]

       product2-own

       [

      productID
      productLength
      arriveTime
       startTime
      finishTime
      waitTime


      ]

      product3-own

      [

      productID
      productLength
      arriveTime
      startTime
      finishTime

       ]


        schedulers-own 

        [

        numJobArrive
        numJobStart
        numJobFinish
        numJobWait
        currentmachineID

        ]


        machine-own 

       [

       machineID
       numJobStart
       numJobFinish
       waitTimeM
       idleTimeM
       nextAvailTime
         currentproductID
       utilization

  ]



  to setup 
    clear-all

    ask patches [set pcolor 8]
    ask patch -3 6 [set pcolor 125]  

    ask patch -3 2 [set pcolor 125]
    ask patch 1 4 [set pcolor black]
     setup-products1
     setup-products2
     setup-products3
     setup-machines

     reset-ticks

  end

  to setup-machines

    create-machine1 1 [setxy -3 6
    set shape "computer server"]
    create-machine2  1[setxy -3 2
    set shape "computer server"]
    create-machine3  1[setxy 1 4
    set shape "computer server"]

  end

  to setup-products1

     create-product1 Job1-products [
      set shape "hexagonal prism"
      set color red
      set size 1.25
      set xcor -14
      set ycor 6
      set heading  90
      separate-products
    ]

  end



  to setup-products2

    create-product2 Job2-products [
      set shape "die 4"
      set color blue
      set xcor -14
      set ycor 4
      set size 1.25
      set heading  90
      separate-products
    ]

  end

  to setup-products3

    create-product3 Job3-products [
      set shape "box"
      set color brown
      set size 1.25
      set xcor -14
      set ycor 2
      set heading  90
      separate-products
    ]

  end




  ; this procedure is needed so when we click "Setup" we
  ; don't end up with any two Products on the same patch
  to separate-products  ;; turtle procedure
    if any? other turtles-here
      [ fd 1.5
        separate-products ]
  end

  to go-product3  
  let totalprod (turtle-set product1 product2 product3)

    let targetmachine1 patch -3 6
     let targetmachine2 patch -3 2
     let targetmachine3 patch 1 4

     if count product3 > 0
     [
  ask one-of product3 [
      if not any? product1-on machine1 or not any? product2-on machine1 

         [
          move-to targetmachine1

         ]
     if not any? product1-on machine2 or not any? product2-on machine2 

         [
          face targetmachine2     
           move-to targetmachine2
         ]

         if not any? product1-on machine3 or not any? product2-on machine3 

         [
          face targetmachine3 
          move-to targetmachine3
          die
  ] 


    ]]
     tick
  end


  to go-product2

      let targetmachine1 patch -3 2
     let targetmachine2 patch 1 4
     if count product2 > 0
     [
  ask one-of product2 [
      if not any? product1-on machine2 or not any? product3-on machine2 

         [

          face targetmachine1      
           move-to targetmachine1
         ]

         if not any? product1-on machine3 or not any? product3-on machine3 

         [

          face targetmachine2 
          move-to targetmachine2
          die
  ] 

   ]]
     tick

  end

  to go-product1


     let targetmachine patch 1 4
     if count product1 > 0
     [

  ask one-of product1
   [
        if not any? product2-on machine3 or not any? product3-on machine3 

         [    
          face targetmachine 
          move-to targetmachine
          die
  ] 
    ]]
     tick
  end


  to go

   let totalprod (turtle-set product1 product2 product3)

     while [count totalprod > 0] [
    if Priority = "0" [
  go-product1
  go-product2   
  go-product3
     ]
    if Priority = "1" [
      while [count product1 > 0][
  go-product1 ]
  go-product2   
  go-product3
     ]
    if Priority = "2" [
      while [count product2 > 0][
  go-product2 ]
  go-product1   
  go-product3
     ]
    if Priority = "3" [
      while [count product3 > 0][
  go-product3 ]
  go-product1   
  go-product2
     ]
    ]

  tick
  end
  ```

Comment: But what is the actual problem? Is it failing somewhere or just not doing what you want?

Comment: At the moment Only 1 turtle at a time is moving towards the target. As there are three Targets i want three turtles to move towards their respective targets at the same time.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible in NetLogo, when you run a model, every agent is asked to do their actions one at a time. I do believe there's something related to threads about NetLogo but I'm not related to this issue. Try reading through the documentation, search for 'thread'.

Comment: As well as the `tick` problem in Seth's answer, your code suggests that you have other conceptual confusions. In particular, you are inconsistent in whether your machines are different breeds (machine-1, machine-2 and machine-3) or are multiple instances of the same breed (ID of 1, 2, or 3 but all machines). It appears that machines are interchangeable and can all deal with all products, so one breed would be more appropriate.Perhaps do some more work with the tutorials, read the programming guide, and study more sample models to try and understand how ABM models think.

Comment: Discrete event simulations (scheduling models) are a little unnatural in ABM, so it would be good to be more comfortable with ABM first, before trying to do something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the calls to `tick` out of your individual `go-product` procedures. It only ever makes sense to call `tick` once in your entire model, and that's at the end of your main `go` procedure.

Remove the uses of `while` from your `go` procedure. Time will pass in your model because `go` is called over and over again in a forever button -- not because you have loops inside your `go` procedure. The forever button is looping enough.

The goal is to structure your model so that each time through `go` (which is to say one tick), only one unit of work or action or motion takes place. Then, as `go` runs over and over again, then longer units of work, that take multiple ticks to accomplish, will appear to take place concurrently.

Nearly every model in Sample Models, including the Tutorial 3 model, is structured this way. You should only have a different structure if you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing and why you're doing it.